# How to concatenate addresses in one declared variable?

Tags: sql, case, sybase, sap-ase

I have current code that builds the string of the addresses like this:

```
    addressStreet = "";
    if(q1.addr1 != "") {
        addressStreet = addressStreet & q1.addr1;
    }

    if(q1.addr2 != "") {
        addressStreet = addressStreet & "<br>" & q1.addr2;
    }

    if(q1.addr3 != "") {
        addressStreet = addressStreet & "<br>" & q1.addr3;
    }

    if(q1.addr4 != "") {
        addressStreet = addressStreet & "<br>" & q1.addr4;
    }
```

`Q1` is query where all columns are located. I was trying to do all of this concatenating in Sybase SQL query. Here is example of what I have tried:

```
DECLARE @AddressStreet VARCHAR(500)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN datalength(address1) > 0 THEN @AddressStreet + address1  
        WHEN datalength(address2) > 0 THEN @AddressStreet + address2
        WHEN datalength(address3) > 0 THEN @AddressStreet + address3
        WHEN datalength(address4) > 0 THEN @AddressStreet + address4
    END AS AddressStr
FROM Info
WHERE recid = 1214
```

Query above produced this result:

```
18 Wolf Street,
```

That result is incorrect because `address2` column has this value: `Suite 408`. The address should look like this:

```
18 Wolf Street,
Suite 408
```

Is there a way to get desired output in Sybase SQL? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `CASE` statement, the first condition that is met is executed. So in your case, length of `address1` is greater than 0 so `@AddressStreet + address1` gets executed, and nothing else. I don't know Sybase well enough to know what functions are available, but you can surely try something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN datalength(address1) > 0 THEN address1 ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN datalength(address2) > 0 THEN address2 ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN datalength(address3) > 0 THEN address3 ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN datalength(address4) > 0 THEN address4 ELSE '' END
       AS AddressStr
  FROM Info
 WHERE recid = 1214
```

This won't have any whitespace between the address fields, so you might want to have something something like `'<BR>' + address2`, etc. if you want it to produce the HTML line breaks.

Comment: You can also use a char(10) in SQL to produce a line break via the ASCII code i.e. address1 + char(10)

Comment: Or char(13) + char(10) for Windows EOL, yeah.